# Add items from front of array to end of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems very simple. Not quiet sure how I am making sure a mess of it.

I have an list. I want to take the first three items front the front and add them to the rear. I dont want to remove the items from the front. I want them to be on the front and on the rear.

So my list starts like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and after I am done with it will look like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3]
```

This list is stored in a `<ul>`

Here is my code

```
_options.slides = $.makeArray($('.slide'));
var el = [];
$.each(_options.slides.splice(0, 3), function (x, item) {
     el.push(item);
});
$('#video-triggers').clone().append(el);  //break point here
```

Someone of the code is probably unnecessary as I have been playing around for this for too long. If I put a break point  on the clone append line and execute the code in the console (development tools) here are the results

[image]

**EDIT**

The clone and append line has my results, but the container doesnt have those results?

Here are the results without the clone

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I also tried this

```
$('#video-triggers').append(_options.slides.concat(el))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your order of operations and variables mixed up . . . you are cloning your target `<ul>`, instead of the `<li>`'s that you want to copy.  Try this . . .

Change this:

```
$('#video-triggers').clone().append(el);
```

. . . to this:

```
el.clone().appendTo($('#video-triggers'));
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. I shall name my first born child after you.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is because you **cloned** it and then you added the new elements to the clone (and the clone does not exist on your page).

Answer (score 1):

Use [unshift();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to push items to front of array.

```
$.each(_options.slides.splice(0, 3), function (x, item) {
     el.push(item);
     el.unshift(item);
});
```

Comment: That doesnt help. After I append with your el using your code I still only see the results once in the array. As [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: Maybe unshift first and then push? =oO

Comment: Ha. el isn't the problem. Its the append. The results are what I want in el, but when I append to the list the duplicate values are not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
b = a.concat(a.slice(0,3));
console.log(b);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The problem is getting the results into a list. I can get the results you show if you look at my first image, but no matter how I append I cant get the results into the <ul> with the duplicate values